# kubernetes integration with python

Tags: python, kubernetes

How to get the list of namespace in kubernetes with RBAC enable using Python.

I have configured kubernetes in my windows and i have config file with cluster info . After running kubectl proxy , I am able to launch UI dashboard .It requires token and once i added the access token , I am able to fetch namespace and pod details .Once after token expired in 60 minutes .

Again ,UI dashboard is asking new token details.Once I provided new access token,it gives

> 403 unauthorized error.

Can someone help me why my new access token is not recognized

Access the namespace , pods after giving new access token

Answer (score 2):

The access token is typically associated with a [Service Account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens). It may be that the service account that you used initially doesn't exist anymore.

It may be that you are using a [Bootstrap Token](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#bootstrap-tokens) that looks something like this: `781292.db7bc3a58fc5f07e` if that's the case, these expire after 60 minutes and you will have to generate a new one. Assuming you created your cluster with [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm/) you can regenerate it like this:

```
$ kubeadm token generate
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to access K8s resources, it better to create `Service Account`, get the token and access. For example, take a look at this `Service Account` [manifest file](https://github.com/veerendra2/my-k8s-applications/blob/master/spinnaker/spinnaker_sa.yaml), specify necessary `RoleBinding`/`ClusterRolebinding` and create `Service Account`

Once done, use this [shell script](https://github.com/veerendra2/my-k8s-applications/blob/master/spinnaker/kubeconfig_generator.sh) to generate kubeconfig file which contains your service account token(which was created in earlier step)

Use that `kubeconfig` file to access kubernetes resources programmatically

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the Kubernetes API from inside the pod, you can create a service account and grant access to that account.

Further you can use code similar to :

```
    import kubernetes, os, sys
    kubernetes.config.load_incluster_config()


    v1 = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api()
```